# MySQL (MariaDB 10.1) find and replace/delete string with REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I have a notes column for products that many contain the following (as well as other info):

```
<p><em><strong>Item dropped from ESP datafeed and pricing removed from site on 02-17-2017. May still be available.</strong></em></p>
```

Where the 02-17-2017 date my change (but will always be in that format). Can I find and delete these strings with just a database query (leaving the rest of the data that is in the column, like a MySQL REPLACE() but with regex to match the dates) or do I need to do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with:

```
UPDATE `ii_Product` 
SET `notes`= REGEXP_REPLACE(`notes`, '\n?<p><em><strong>Item dropped from ESP datafeed and pricing removed from site on .*\. May still be available.<\/strong><\/em><\/p>\n?\n?', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE notes LIKE '<p><em><strong>Item dropped from ESP datafeed and pricing removed from site on %. May still be available.</strong></em></p>'
```

Note that I put a `%` in the string.

I don't understand "delete those strings" -- Do you want to replace them with the empty string?  `NULL`?  Delete the *row* containing that in the `notes` column?  Something else?  I hope that the `WHERE` clause is sufficient to get you moving in the right direction.

Note:  `REGEXP` is 'overkill'; `LIKE` suffices.

If you want to remove the date but keep the rest of the string, then won't this do?...

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET notes = '<p><em><strong>Item dropped from ESP datafeed and pricing removed from site on xxxxxxxxxxx. May still be available.</strong></em></p>'
    WHERE notes LIKE '<p><em><strong>Item dropped from ESP datafeed and pricing removed from site on %. May still be available.</strong></em></p>';
```

(Or whatever you would like to put as a placeholder.)

MariaDB-10.0.5 has these:  REGEXP_REPLACE(), REGEXP_INSTR(), and REGEXP_SUBSTR(); but I don't see that they are necessary for your case.

Comment: I need to find that specific string and delete it, leaving the rest of the data in the column. Basically a REPLACE() but with regex to match the dates.

Comment: There is other data around this string that contains the date. So e.g.
_blah blah blah
<p><em><strong>Item dropped from ESP datafeed and pricing removed from site on 02-17-2017. May still be available.</strong></em></p>
blah blah blah_
and I want to remove 
_<p><em><strong>Item dropped from ESP datafeed and pricing removed from site on 02-17-2017. May still be available.</strong></em></p>_
while leaving the _blah blah blah_ and _blah blah blah_

Comment: OK, then add `%` at start and end of the `LIKE` string:  `LIKE '%<p>...on % ... </p>%'` and hope that there are not edge cases or spelling variants that invalidate this search.

Comment: Your solution doesn't remove the string. See my solution below.